# Microsoft Entity Framework link table issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was hoping someone could give me a bit of advice here. I am wondering if I am on track or way off base in my approach. I am using Entity Framework, database first approach. I have a link table that associates people to each other. Person 1 associated to Person 2 as a friend for example. (association_type holds a key value associated to a lookup table)

[image]

I noticed that Entity Framework creates two separate navigation properties.

```
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("IntelDBModel", "FK_a_Person_Person_t_Person", "a_Person_Person")]
    public EntityCollection<a_Person_Person> a_Person_Person
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("IntelDBModel", "FK_a_Person_Person_t_Person1", "a_Person_Person")]
    public EntityCollection<a_Person_Person> a_Person_Person1
```

In other parts of the application, I have successfully used Entity Framework to write data to the database. For example, I have a person to telephone relationship.

[image]

In the person to telephone scenario, I create a t_Person (p) object, then create a t_Telephone (t) object and use p.t_Telephone.Add(t);

That seems to work fine.

I am somewhat lost in terms of how to manage this person to person link table insert.

When saving to the database, I use foreach to iterate through the People objects.

```
foreach (t_Person p in People)
{ctx.t_Person.AddObject(p);
...
}
```

I know what person is associated to what person in this People object collection. However, I don't know how to utilize the t_Person navigation properties (a_Person_Person) to save the person1 and person2 values to the link table (a_Person_Person).

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with ASP.NET

Comment: that is why i stopped using entity framework for complex solutions and came back for T-SQL and stored procedures,,,,

Answer (score 0):

I think the given situation will generally give you hard time when using EF, since you are linking two foreign key two one table with same Primary key, since the relationship or lazy loading would be difficult to handle you might get double records or wrong records, I would add another property to the t_person table like datecreated  which would make the the EF treat t_person table as not an  association,  but as actual entity giving you more control over entity and insertion and deletion.